# How to create separate resource files for debugging and releasing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, embedded-resource

Is it possible to create two files, for example `Text.Debug.resx` and `Text.Release.resx`, where the appropriate resource file is automatically loaded during debugging and releasing of the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd wrap the ResourceManager:

```
public class Resources
{
    private readonly ResourceManager _resourceManager;

    public Resources()
    {
#if DEBUG
        const string configuration = "Debug";
#else
        const string configuration = "Release";
#endif

        _resourceManager = new ResourceManager($"StackOverflow.Text.{configuration}", typeof(Resources).Assembly);
    }

    public string GetString(string resourceKey)
    {
        return _resourceManager.GetString(resourceKey);
    }
}
```

Obviously, amend the namespace appropriately when newing up the manager.

#### Edit

You could also implement it as a static class to avoid having to new up an instance of the wrapper:

```
public static class Resources
{
    private static ResourceManager _resourceManager;

    public static string GetString(string resourceKey)
    {
        if (_resourceManager != null)
        {
            return _resourceManager.GetString(resourceKey);
        }

#if DEBUG
        const string configuration = "Debug";
#else
        const string configuration = "Release";
#endif

        _resourceManager = new ResourceManager($"StackOverflow.Text.{configuration}", typeof(Resources).Assembly);

        return _resourceManager.GetString(resourceKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: But this way Visual Studio will not auto-generate the properties so `var a = Text.deerName;` will not work anymore

Comment: Just do Resources.GetString("deerName"). I'm don't think it's possible to do what you're suggesting without writing a plug-in for Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Create 2 subdirectories under Properties: Debug and Release.  Copy your Resources.resx and Resources.Designer.cs files to each of those directory.  It will regenerate the Resources.Designer.cs file with a namespace ProjectName.Properties.Debug or ProjectName.Properties.Release.  Edit the .csproj file to put an appropriate condition on those files, along these lines:

```
<Compile Include="Properties\Debug\Resources.Designer.cs" Condition="$(Configuration.StartsWith('Debug')) ">
   ...

<EmbeddedResource Include="Properties\Debug\Resources.resx" Condition="$(Configuration.StartsWith('Debug'))">
   ...
```

Then add a Resources.cs file to the Properties directory, and use #if DEBUG to determine if it inherits from Properties.Debug.Resources or Properties.Release.Resources:

```
namespace ProjectName.Properties
{
    class Resources
#if DEBUG
        : ProjectName.Properties.Debug.Resources
#else
        : ProjectName.Properties.Release.Resources
#endif
    {
    }
}
```